# Tor Browser Bundle does not work in Slitaz (Linux Dist)

Tags: configuration

Does anyone know why and especially how to get TBB to work in Linux dist. Slitaz ?

```
Update:
TBB now works with "tor-browser-linux32-6.0.2_en-US.tar.xz" in the "SliTaz-rolling-core64.iso" from 2016-07-24.

Procedure:
Extract the Tor Browser file (not as root):
Unxz c tor-browser-linux32-6.0.2_en-US.tar.xz | tar xf -

Install from terminal window as root:
Tazpkg get-install bash and answer Yes to the default shell.
Tazpkg get-install gxmessage
Tazpkg get-install xorg-xmessage
Tazpkg get-install libmagic
Tazpkg get-install file

getconf is not in Slitaz package repository, but TBB works 100% OK without.

Big thanks to "canonizing ironize".
```

Comment: Can you tell us *why* it doesn't work? If you run `./Browser/start-tor-browser --debug` you should get some output that will help diagnose why, also check in `dmesg` to see if there any reports of firefox crashing.

Comment: When I from LXTerminal gives the command "./start-tor-browser" or "./start-tor-browser --debug" I get the following error message "env: can not execute 'bash': No such file or directory".
If I activate the file "Tor Browser Setup" in the "home / tux / Downloads / Thu-browser_en-US" from the graphical file manager "PCmanFM" which I previously could in Debian, Linux Mint and various Arch distributions, then cursor turn around for 20 seconds then stops with no error messages.

Comment: So you don't have `bash`, there's your problem.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're failing to start Tor Browser is that you do not have `bash` installed.

As per [their documentation](http://doc.slitaz.org/en:handbook:systemutils#bash-shell), you need to install bash, however you don't need to "edit the /etc/passwd file with your favorite text editor and change your shell" *(Ew!)* it just needs to be installed and somewhere within one of the directories in `$PATH` so that it can be found by `env`.

Update:

You're also missing some other tools that the script uses, `getconf` and `file` which are standard system utilities normally available under GNUs `coreutils`.

I anticipate further problems once you've solved those. Likely with missing libraries like dbus-glib or others required by `firefox` itself.

Also if you're using a i386 userspace then you should be using 32bit tor browser, even if the kernel is amd64 otherwise you're probably going to end up with multilib hell.